# Using LS To Show The Date Modified And A Specific Number Of Files

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I am using `ls -t | head -8` to show the last 8 files modified in a directory, but this only prints the file name.

Is there a way to alter the above command so that it shows the modified date for the file names as well?

Comment: Use the `-l` (ell) switch: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-l+-t

Comment: @PerlDuck - that shows the permissions the owner etc.  I am only wanting the file name and the modified date.  Is that possible?

Comment: Not with `ls` alone. But you just got a nice answer using `stat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/stat.1.html) to get the file metadata:

```
stat -c $'%y\t%n' * | sort -n | head -8
```

Answer (score 3):

`stat` is an easy way, but it can’t print the timestamp in a format like `ls -l`. If you want more fine-grained control over the format, use `find` with the `-printf` option instead, e.g. for an (almost) `ls -l`-like format:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+#%Tb %Td %TH:%TM\t%p\n" | sort -rn | cut -d# -f2- | head -8
```

The `%T+` is needed to sort the output properly and gets removed by `cut` aftwerwards. Read [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html) to find out more about the`find`’s powerful `-printf` option.

#### Example run

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 0 May 30 20:22 last week
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 0 Jun  6 17:22 today
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 0 Jun  5 17:22 yesterday
$ stat -c $'%y\t%n' * | sort -n
2018-05-30 20:22:29.919608691 +0200     last week
2018-06-05 17:22:10.207084356 +0200     yesterday
2018-06-06 17:22:01.940284127 +0200     today
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+#%Tb %Td %TH:%TM\t%p\n" | sort -rn | cut -d# -f2-
Jun 06 17:22    ./today
Jun 05 17:22    ./yesterday
May 30 20:22    ./last week
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+#%Tc\t%p\n" | sort -rn | cut -d# -f2-
Wed 06 Jun 2018 05:22:01 PM CEST        ./today
Tue 05 Jun 2018 05:22:10 PM CEST        ./yesterday
Wed 30 May 2018 08:22:29 PM CEST        ./last week
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort -rn
2018-06-06+17:22:01.9402841270  ./today
2018-06-05+17:22:10.2070843560  ./yesterday
2018-05-30+20:22:29.9196086910  ./last week
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` command is not the most appropriate tool to use in this situation, as shown by other answers. There is a convoluted way to extract the information you want from the output of `ls`, though it does have limitations. It's quite a good example of how working with `ls` can quickly become complicated.

The specific issue with this chain of commands is that the use of the `tr` command removes any multiple occurrences of whitespace and replaces with a single whitespace. This will affect filenames, making them unsuitable for parsing by a machine. Parsing ls is a discouraged activity generally though.

```
ls -lrt| tail -4| tr -s ' '| cut -d ' ' -f6-| tac
```

The reverse ordering of `ls` results, with the `-r` option, is used to avoid the 'Total' line output by the `-l` option of `ls`, and `tac` is used at the end to reorder the results after trimming away the unwanted output.